# Tool for reinforcing XML, XSD and WSDL Naming convention

Tags: wsdl, naming-conventions

In Java we have a wonderful tool named CheckStyle that reinforce all our corporate naming conventions. Wonderful tool. I would like to do the same with our XSD and WSDL.

Is there a tools that I could use to reinforce and make sure all coders and analysts will respect conventions like:

> <wsdl:operation name="XX>  All operations must start with getXX of setXX or deleteXX.

Is the solution to my problem to create an XSD to validate my WSDL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this tool for the defining rules and running them on WSDL, mainly for naming conventions:

*[Rule Engine Based Wsdl Auditor](http://wsdlauditor.sourceforge.net)*

Answer (score 0):

The development of [Wsdl Auditor](http://wsdlauditor.sourceforge.net) as mentioned by Saikiran Daripelli seems to have stopped. Last commit in the Subversion repository is from Januar 2011.

After doing some research, installing and testing several tools I decided to use [Oracle Code Compliance Inspector](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/doc.1111/e17366/chapter20.htm) (CCI) which is available as an extension for JDeveloper IDE and as a command line utility (which allows integration with e.g. Ant as well).

Testing for naming conventions seems not to be the primary goal of Oracle CCI but it works quite good by using XPath + regular expression. As mentioned on their website the primary objective is to enforce design consistency and good coding and documentation practices.